# Print key value pairs from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to pretty-print the key-value pairs of a dictionary. I have the following code:

```py
dict = {'AAAAA': 2, 'BB': 1, 'CCCCCCCCC': 85}

for k, v in dict.items():
    print('{}........{}'.format(k, v))
```

This is what my code currently produces:

```
AAAAA........2
BB........1
CCCCCCCCC........85
```

But I want:

```
AAAAA............2
BB...............1
CCCCCCCCC........85
```

How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `len()` to balance out the number of dots

```
dict = {'AAAAA': 2, 'BB': 1, 'CCCCCCCCC': 85}

total = 15
for k, v in dict.items():
    print(k, "." * (total - len(k)), v, sep="")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **f-string** you can set the width of each field and pad with `.`

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
dict = {'AAAAA': 2, 'BB': 1, 'CCCCCCCCC': 85}

for k, v in dict.items():
    print(f'{k:.<10}{v:.>10}')
```

giving

```
AAAAA..............2
BB.................1
CCCCCCCCC.........85
```

or

```
    print(f'{k:.<20}{v}')
```

if you really want

```
AAAAA...............2
BB..................1
CCCCCCCCC...........85
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.ljust()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust):

```py
dictionary = {'AAAAA': 2, 'BB': 1, 'CCCCCCCCC': 85}
n = 17

for key, value in dictionary.items():
    justified_key = key.ljust(n, ".")
    print(f"{justified_key}{value}")
```

This outputs:

```
AAAAA............2
BB...............1
CCCCCCCCC........85
```

Comment: Would be more "readable" to align units (2,1,5) together ;)

Comment: What units are you referring to?

Comment: In your result, 2,1 and 5 should be vertically aligned.

Comment: That's not what's wanted in the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It adapts to the length of your k,v:

```
dict = {'AAAAA': 2, 'BB': 1, 'CCCCCCCCC': 85}

for k, v in dict.items():
    print(f'{k}{(20-(len(k)+len(str(v))))*"."}{v}')

AAAAA..............2
BB.................1
CCCCCCCCC.........85
```